# To control default opening software for PDF centrally?

Tags: pdf, defaults

I want PDF documents open with Preview, not Adobe Reader.
I select Open With > Other > Click the Box Always Open With.
However, this does affect all pdf-files in my system.

**How can you set the default program for PDF?**

Comment: What do you mean with different? You said you want pdf to open with preview and you described the solution yourself already...

Comment: @Rob It is not a permanent solution. Although you press it, it will not stay. Adobe reader will continue be the default.

Comment: I simplified the question so you do not get confused by controlling all programs in your systems, but just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Get Info window for any PDF, there should be a section called **Open With**. You can choose an application from the pop-up menu (Mine says Preview, since I've already changed it, but yours will say Adobe Reader).

Once you change that to Preview, you can click on the **Change All** button to make it so all PDF documents open with Preview. Mine is grayed out for the same reason; all PDFs on my account open in Preview by default.

[image: Get Info window]